# Tomcat & Apache with mod_jk partly working

Tags: grails, apache2, tomcat7, mod-jk

I have a grails app running on a tomcat server that is pointed to by apache 2.2 http server. Using mod_jk I've gotten it to work using myapp.com:9090 to get to the app. However myapp.com just gives me 503 with the error:

"Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 193.xx.xxx.xxx for ServerName."

But this is the only error I get.
The virtual host looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 193.xx.xxx.xxx:80>
ServerName www.myapp.se
ServerAlias myapp.se
DocumentRoot "D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.5/webapps/ROOT"
JkMount  /* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

In the httpd.conf i load the module like this:

```
 # Load module
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
# Where to find workers.properties
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
# Where to put jk logs
JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log
# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel    emerg
# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
# JkOptions indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE,
JkOptions     +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
# JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
JkRequestLogFormat     "%w %V %T"
```

And the workers.properties looks like this:

```
workers.tomcat_home="D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.5"
workers.java_home="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_22"
ps=/
worker.list=worker1

worker.worker1.port=8010
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried mod_proxy_ajp?  I have a Grails app in production that uses Apache 2.2, Tomcat 6x, Grails 1.3.7 with Apache proxying to Tomcat w/o issue using mod_proxy_ajp.  If you're not restricted to using mod_jk, I recommend giving this a try.  And I have this working on Centos 5.5, Ubuntu 10.4LTS and Win2k3 environments, FYI.